# How do I troubleshoot my computer crashing with BSOD 7F?

Tags: windows-xp, crash, bsod

One of my end users is experiencing an issue with her laptop crashing a couple times a day and I'm trying to figure out what is causing the problem.

The event properties for the system crash show the following:

> Event Type: Error
>   Event Source: System Error
>   Event Category: (102)
>   Event ID: 1003
>
> Date:  9/14/2010
>   Time:  11:01:34 AM
>
> Description:
>
> Error code 0000007f,
>   parameter1 00000000, parameter2 00000000, parameter3 00000000, parameter4 00000000.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when the system [divided by a zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221161514/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.divideby0.html) somewhere, the cause is who got the zero there.

Straight from [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/) documentation for [bug check 7F](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7f--unexpected-kernel-mode-trap):

> **Troubleshooting:**
>
> If you recently added hardware to the computer, remove it to see if the error recurs. If existing hardware has failed, remove or replace the faulty component. Run hardware diagnostics that the system manufacturer supplies to determine which hardware component failed.
>
> The memory scanner is especially important. Faulty or mismatched memory can cause this bug check. For more informaiton about these procedures, see the owner's manual for your computer. Check that all adapter cards in the computer are properly seated. Use an ink eraser or an electrical contact treatment, available at electronics supply stores, to ensure adapter card contacts are clean.
>
> If the error appears on a newly installed system, check the availability of updates for the BIOS, the SCSI controller, or network cards. These kind of updates are typically available on the Web site or BBS of the hardware manufacturer.
>
> Confirm that all hard disk drives, hard disk controllers, and SCSI adapters are listed in the Microsoft Windows Marketplace Tested Products List.
>
> If the error occurred after the installation of a new or updated device driver, you should remove or replace the driver. If, under this circumstance, the error occurs during the startup sequence and the system partition is formatted with NTFS, you might be able to use Safe Mode to rename or delete the faulty driver. If the driver is used as part of the system startup process in Safe Mode, you have to start the computer by using the Recovery Console in order to access the file.
>
> Also restart your computer, and then press F8 at the character-based menu that displays the operating system choices. At the Advanced Options menu, select the Last Known Good Configuration option. This option is most effective when you add only one driver or service at a time.
>
> Overclocking (setting the CPU to run at speeds above the rated specification) can cause this error. If you have overclocked the computer that is experiencing the error, return the CPU to the default clock speed setting.
>
> Check the System Log in Event Viewer for additional error messages that might help identify the device or driver that is causing the error. You can also disable memory caching of the BIOS to try to resolve the problem.
>
> If you encountered this error while upgrading to a new version of the Windows operating system, the error might be caused by a device driver, a system service, a virus scanner, or a backup tool that is incompatible with the new version. If possible, remove all third-party device drivers and system services and disable any virus scanners before you upgrade. Contact the software manufacturer to obtain updates of these tools. Also make sure that you have installed the latest Windows Service Pack.
>
> Finally, if all the above steps do not resolve the error, take the system motherboard to a repair facility for diagnostic testing. A crack, a scratched trace, or a defective component on the motherboard can also cause this error.

If that doesn't help, check the following directories for *.DMP files.

- C:\Windows (MEMORY.DMP)
- C:\Windows\Minidump

Compress and upload the most recent one, this allows me to do further debugging.

Comment: Am I able to upload the minidump here or do I need to upload it to an external site?

Comment: I uploaded it here...thanks for helping me out. http://www.woofiles.com/dl-206189-QXhDyAH6-Mini09141002.zip

Comment: Looks like a driver fault because bcmwl5.sys did this, you should install the newest Broadcom Wireless Drivers.

Comment: Hopefully that is all it is! Thanks for taking a look...going to update the drivers now and will let you guys know.

Comment: Driver updated with the most recent one I could locate. Hopefully that will take care of the issue.

Comment: Well after updating the driver, when the system boots up now it doesn't move past showing the desktop. The user logs in but the taskbar, desktop icons, etc. never show up.

Comment: Run a memtest on the machine.  If you have a Linux live CD sitting around, most have memtest on them, otherwise google for a download.

Comment: Hmm, that is odd behavior... Does it happen every boot?